# Show different Customizer Settings on Page-Tamplates

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-customizer, api

Heyo,

is it possible to show different `Customizersettings` in the `Customizer API` when you switch between two pages and each page has a different `Template`?

For example: `Page-1` has the template `Custom-Sidebar` and `Page-2` has the template `Custom-Fullwidth`. Now when I go into the `Customizer` and view `Page-1` I want to show `Settings` for the `Sidebar` and when I change to `Page-2` I want to show `Settings` for *Images* and other stuff ... but **not** for the `Sidebar`! (If that makes sense)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customizer API offers `active_callback` methods on both the [control](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_area_customize_control/active_callback/) andd [section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_section/active_callback/) classes. Basically you use either an conditional or a custom function to determine if a control or section is shown to the user.

If you want a section to appear only for pages, you would do somthing like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'wpse_283821_acme_pages', array(
    'title' => 'Acme Pages Section',
    'description' => 'Edit the ACME Pages Sections',
    'priority' => 20,
    'active_callback' => 'is_page',
) );
```

Or maybe a specific custom function:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'wpse_283821_acme_special_page', array(
    'title' => 'Acme Special Page Section',
    'description' => 'Edit the Specific ACME Page Section',
    'priority' => 20,
    'active_callback' => 'wpse_283821_acme_custom_callback',
) );

wpse_283821_acme_custom_callback() {
    // Do your logic here
    if ( true !== $condition ){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are some questions on WPSE with good answers showing interesting uses of `active_callback`. Check [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/272410/22694) and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/249809/22694). And there is [this post](https://blog.josemcastaneda.com/2015/07/23/using-active-callbacks-in-the-customizer/) with a use case just like yours.

I could just copy them here, but i Think it's worth taking a look at those questions, answers, comments and code to get a deeper understanding.